# Paths from .egg file not working (os.path.dirname)

Tags: python, scrapy

I have a Scrapy spider that is using `gettext` to translate some strings. The localization files is stored in `/locale/`.

When I load the translation I do it with the following code:

```
t = gettext.translation('sv', localedir=LOCALE_DIR, languages=['sv'])
```

`LOCALE_DIR` is set in settings.py with the following code:

```
import os
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__))
LOCALE_DIR = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'locale')
```

This works great when I run the code locally with `scrapy crawl spider`. But when I deploy it to `scrapyd`, it generates an .egg file and the localization files can no longer be found. When I print the `LOCALE_DIR` from the deployed version. It gives me `/tmp/condobot-1428391146-4QuH3E.egg/locale`.

I guess this is the reason why the files can not be found. The path is a subfolder of a file, which does not make sense. What I expected was that the .egg file would be extracted into a folder, and the path would point to `/tmp/condobot-1428391146-4quh3e/locale`.

- Is there another, better way of setting the path to `LOCALE_DIR` than the way that I currently do it? I have also tried setting it to `locale` without any better results.

EDIT: I do use a `setup.py` file with the following code:

```
from setuptools import setup, find_packages

setup(
    name         = 'project',
    version      = '1.0',
    packages     = find_packages(),
    entry_points = {'scrapy': ['settings = condobot.settings']},
    package_data = {
        # If any package contains *.txt or *.rst files, include them:
        '': ['*.mo', '*.po', '*.txt'],
    },
)
```

I also tried using the following setup.py with a MANIFEST.in file:

```
from setuptools import setup, find_packages

setup(
    name = 'project',
    install_requires = ['distribute'],
    version = '1.0',
    packages = find_packages(),
    entry_points = {'scrapy': ['settings = condobot.settings']},
    include_package_data = True,
    zip_safe = False,
)
```

MANIFEST.in

```
recursive-include locale *
recursive-include condobot/locale *
```

My file structure looks like this:

```
- condobot
    - locale
        - sv
            - LC_MESSAGES
                sv.mo
    pipelines.py
    settings.py
- locale
    - sv
        - LC_MESSAGES
            sv.mo
MANIFEST.in
requirements.txt
scrapy.cfg
setup.py
```

(I have placed the /locale/ folder both in / and in /condobot/ just to make sure that the path is not wrong.)

I have extracted the .egg file and I can confirm that it does include the `/locale/` folder, and in the `/locale/` folder there is `/locale/sv/LC_MESSAGES/sv.mo` and `/locale/sv/LC_MESSAGES/sv.po`.

So the issue does not seem to be that the setup.py file is not including the files in the `.egg` file. It seems to be that the path `/......./file.egg/locale/` does not work.

Comment: Without more information we can't help you, but I suggest the following: does it use a `setup.py` file to generate the `.egg`? Do you have the files in `locale` specified in the `MANIFEST.in` file? `/tmp/condobot-1428391146-4QuH3E.egg/` is not a file, it's a directory that contains the extracted contents of the egg and if `locale` isn't packaged it won't be there.

Comment: I added the setup.py code. And I can confirm that locale IS packaged in the .egg file. If I rename it to a .zip file and unzip it, its right there, with the files inside of it.

Comment: Are you missing the `__init__.py` file (from the condobot dir)?

Comment: No, the __init__.py file is there.

Comment: @MarcusLind can you make a small github repo that demonstrates the issue?

Answer (score 0):

One way to be sure that any other non-source file is accessible after the python module is packaged as an egg is to specify `zip_safe` as `False` to have the package fully extracted when installed, i.e.:

```
setup(
    name         = 'project',
    version      = '1.0',
    ...
    zip_safe     = False,
)
```

Comment: I tried, did not help. Not sure if it working correctly though, when I deploy the Scrapy crawler to Scrapyd with zip_safe = False, it still deploys an .egg file and there is no extracted folder.